# Merging Embedded Lists with Different Date Formats in R

Tags: r, list, date, merge, regression

I need to merge two lists with each other but I am not getting what I want and I think it is because the `"Date"` column is in two different formats. I have a list called `li` and in this list there are 12 lists each with the following format:

```
> tail(li$fxe)
           Date           fxe
3351 2020-06-22  0.0058722768
3352 2020-06-23  0.0044256216
3353 2020-06-24 -0.0044998220
3354 2020-06-25 -0.0027309539
3355 2020-06-26  0.0002832672
3356 2020-06-29  0.0007552346
```

I am trying to merge each of these unique lists with a different list called `factors` which looks like :

```
> tail(factors)
         Date  Mkt-RF   SMB   HML    RF
3351 20200622  0.0071  0.83 -1.42 0.000
3352 20200623  0.0042  0.15 -0.56 0.000
3353 20200624 -0.0261 -0.52 -1.28 0.000
3354 20200625  0.0112  0.25  0.50 0.000
3355 20200626 -0.0243  0.16 -1.37 0.000
3356 20200629  0.0151  1.25  1.80 0.000
```

The reason I need this structure is because I am trying to send them to a function I wrote to do linear regressions. But the first line of my function aims to merge these lists. When I merge them I end up with a null structure even thought my lists clearly have the same number of rows. In my function `df` is `li`. The embedded list of `li` is confusing me. Can someone help please?

Function I want to use:

```
Bf <- function(df, fac){
#This function calculates the beta of the french fama factor #using linear regression
#Input: df = a dataframe containg returns of the security
# fac = dataframe containing excess market retrun and
# french fama 3 factor
#Output: a Beta vectors of the french fama model
temp <- merge(df, fac, by="Date")
temp <- temp[, !names(temp) %in% "Date"]
temp[ ,1] <- temp[,1] - temp$RF return(lm(temp[,1]~temp[,2]+temp[,3]+temp[,4])$coeff)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

a: you are dealing with data frames and not lists
b: if you want to merge them, you need to modify the factors$date column to match that of li$fxe$date

try to do:

```
factors$date <- as.Date(strptime(factors$date, format = "%Y%M%d"))
```

This should convert, the factors column to "Date" format.